Django FormField that creates several inputs and maps them to model fields
I am using django-modeltranslation to have certain fields of my models in multiple languages. For example, I translate the name field, which leads to several fields in the model and database, like name, name_en, name_gr, etc..
Now I want the user to be able to edit the name and it's translations in a form. And I want the user to be able to select the language they want to edit, so I want to render all fields (i.e. name_en, name_gr) and add some JS to show only one of them and select others.
Now I could easily add both fields to the form, add them to a template and add the JS. However I have several forms with these multilingual fields and would prefer to find a generic solution as custom form field. So something like this:
class MultilingualForm(ModelForm):
    name = MultilingualField()

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ["name"]

However I cannot think of a way on how to map a custom form field to several model fields. I this even possible?
